# I have some code that I would like to turn to linq

Tags: linq, foreach

I have this piece of code where highAmtCtrList is a list of Outstanding contracts that have to be updated and comCtrList is a list of Dilution contracts from which I update highAmtCtrList.

So, for each conctract in highAmtCtrList, if I find a matching contract in comCtrList, I update it with the amount returned from comCtrList.

The code works, it's just that I would like to change it to linq.

Any ideas.
tks in advance.
Rui Martins

```
foreach (Outstanding outCtr in highAmtCtrList)
{
    Dilution dilCtr = 
        comCtrList.FirstOrDefault(dil => dil.Contract == outCtr.Contract);
    if (dilCtr != null) outCtr.Amount += dilCtr.Amount;
}
```

Comment: The line `Dilution dilCtr = 
        comCtrList.FirstOrDefault(dil => dil.Contract == contract.Contract);` never uses `outCtr`. Is this a bug? If not, move it outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. You can write all this in one line, but IMO it's a less maintainable code:

```
outCtr.Join(comCtrList, 
    o => o.Contract, 
    i => i.Contract, 
    (o, i) => o.Amount += i.Amount);
```

EDIT: to sum only first matches:

```
outCtr.ForEach(o => o.Amount += comCtrList
   .Where(i => i.Contract == o.Contract)
   .Select(i => i.Amount)
   .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: I know, but I've had complaints about too much coding. Tks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
foreach (Outstanding o in highAmtCtrList)
{
    o.Amount += comCtrList.Where(d => d.Contract == o.Contract)
                          .Select(d => d.Amount)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Here's another alternative:

```
foreach (Outstanding o in highAmtCtrList)
{
    o.Amount += comCtrList.Where(d => d.Contract == o.Contract)
                          .Take(1)
                          .Sum(d => d.Amount);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing only the `Take...Sum` solution works. Since in the case that no items make it through the `Where` in the `FirstOrDefault` approach this is the equivalent of `o.Amount += null`. The reason it work with the `Take...Sum` is that `Sum` returns zero when asked to sum no-elements.

Comment: @MarkByers I was mistaken - I'm so accustomed to seeing `FirstOrDefault()` used with reference-types that I always think of default meaning `null`. In this case, default means zero and both will work. +1.